# Spectral radius and maximum degree of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spectral-radius

How can I show that the spectral radius of a graph $G$ is less than or equal to its maximum degree?

I have an unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$, where $V$ is its vertex set and $E$ its edge set. The degree of a vertex $x$ is $d_x$ and $D(G)$ if defined as $D(G)=\max\{d_x,x\in V\}$. In the paper I'm reading, the spectral radius is defined as $R(G)=\limsup_{n \to \infty}(A^n(x,y))^{1/n}$, where $A^n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of the adjacency matrix of $G$, but usually it's defined as the largest of its eigenvalues in absolute value. I want to see the intuition behind the inequality $R(G) \le D(G)$.

Comment: Could you clarify or provide a formulism so we can use the same symbols? What kind of graph is it? Weighted ? Unweighted

Comment: Sorry about that lack of information. I'm not used to graph theory, but in this case I think is a unweighted graph. If I have a graph $G=(V,E)$, where $V$ is its vertex set and $E$ its edge set. The degree of a vertex if $d_x$ and $D(G)$ if defined as $D(G)=max\{d_x, x \in V\}$. In the papel I'm reading, the spectral radius is defined as $R(G)=limsup_{n \to \infty}(A^{n}(x,y))^{1/n}$, where $A^n$ is the nth power of the adjacency matrix of $G$, but usually it's defined as the largest of its eigenvalues in absolute value. I wanna see why $R(G) \leq D(G)$, even if it's in an informal way